# JSON schema AND/OR for array enum

Tags: operators, jsonschema

I'd like to specify JSON schema to restrict combinations of array values.

For example if I have an array where the values could be "apple", "orange" or "banana", but "apple" and "orange" would never appear together.

i.e. these are all valid

```
[]
["apple"]
["orange"]
["banana"]
["apple, "banana"]
["orange", "banana"]
```

but these are NOT valid:

```
["apple","orange"]
["apple","orange","banana"]
```

I've got as far as the an enum array, but I'm not sure whether I can specify an OR operator somehow:

```
"options": 
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
      "apple",
      "orange", 
      "banana"
    ]
  }
}
```

p.s. `["apple","apple"]` would also be invalid, but perhaps that's another story.

Comment: BTW, you can check that each item only appears once with `uniqueItems: true`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a combination of `not`, `allOf`, and `contains`.

`not` inverts the validation result.

`allOf` requires that all of the subschemas are valid.

`contains` requires that the array contains an item that is valid according to the subschema value.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["apple","orange","banana"]
  },
  "not": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "contains": {
          "const": "apple"
        }
      },
      {
        "contains": {
          "const": "orange"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/C835R