# JSON Schema validation for a complex comination of AND/OR

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351779/json-schema-and-or-for-array-enum). But it's a little more complicated because I need to validate fields in a list of objects.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "All the Fruits",
  "type": "object",

  "properties":
  {
    "fruit":
    {
      "enum":
      [
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "banana",
        "watermelon",
        "all_fruit"
      ]
    }
  },

  "required":
  [
    "fruit"
  ],

  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

And it's used here in a different file:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Fruit basket",
    "type": "object",

    "properties":
    {
        "type":
        {
            "enum":
            [
                "fruit_basket"
            ]
        },
        "fruits":
        {
            "description": "List of fruits",
            "type": "array",
            "items":
            {
                "$ref": "fruit/fruits.schema.json#"
            },
            "uniqueItems": true,
           {
              // What do I add here?
           }
          
        }

            "required":
            [
                "fruits"
            ]

    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Is there a way to validate JSON such that I can pick any subset of fruits or "all_fruit" not both.

Valid cases:

```
["apple","orange"]
["apple","banana"]
["all_fruit"]
```

Invalid:

```
["all_fruit", "apple"]
```

`all_fruit` cannot exist with anything else.

Edit:

I tried this:

```
...
...
  "uniqueItems": true,
            "if" : {
                "properties": {
                    "fruits": {
                        "const": "all_fruit"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "maxItems": 1,
                "minItems": 1
            }
...
...
```

But the condition seems to be satisfied always. Even when I don't use `all_fruit` and the validation errors out saying `maxItems` expected is 1.

Comment: With complex cases you might be better off writing some code to validate the object rather than try to express it in JsonSchema

Comment: @bhspencer Yeah. That's my backup option. I was wondering if there was a way to do this using JsonSchema

Answer (score 1):

See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html and https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html
-- in pseudocode, you'd want:

- if the list is exactly the value of `["all_fruit"]`,
- then maximum items is 1.

If "all_fruit" could coexist with some values but not all, you could instead use `contains` instead of `const` for the conditional.

Comment: This is a good shout. It's definitely better than the complicated nested `not`, `allOf` and `anyOf` combinations that I was trying. But the issue is that the condition always satisfies to `true` for some reason. Edited the question after trying the `if` condition